# PHP files not getting parsed?

Tags: centos, php5, httpd, apache-2.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with php and apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/178155/problem-with-php-and-apache)

I have php 5.1.6 running on my CentOS 5 server running Apache 2.2.3

when i use command php -v it says

PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Nov 29 2010 16:47:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies

and after creating a my_file.php on var/www/html folder and running command

php -f my_file.php i got the output as "Hello World!"

all fi9 till here but when i upload file through filezilla on server and run the pages through browser then php instead of getting parsed just get printed in the form of simple text.

I am not able to see any LoadModule of PHP5 on http.conf file and when i add it manually
and restart my httpd then my php file instead of being executed, it just get downloaded.

May be any config issue. can any one help me out from this ? Please ask if any other info needed to find the solution.

Comment: There's already a bunch of questions from ppl with the same problem. It's most likely a missing addhandler in apache, see http://serverfault.com/questions/178155/problem-with-php-and-apache.

Comment: None of the replies there worked for me. So i posted it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have defined suitable type and handlers for php. My CentOS system has the following php related definitions

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

Comment: Thanks for looking. i have AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
 this on my httpd.conf for php config.

Comment: I removed my lines and added instead the lines you suggested but problem remained the same. Browser just prints php script as plain text.